# React remount on Router change

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a simple post component in reactjs, this component print post data from db based on id, the id is picked from url (I use react router for this) and the data are picked by an ajax call. The problem is that when I change page the component non update the content, the update happen only when I refresh the page.

```
class Post extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      thePost: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
axios.get(endpoint.posts+'/getpost/'+this.props.match.params.id, cfg)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    thePost: res.data.thePost || ''
                });
        })      
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div>POST { this.props.match.params.id } - { JSON.stringify(this.state.thePost, null, 0) }</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Now the problem is that componentDidMount isn't called on every page change, how I force remount? or I need to move the ajax call in other lifecycle part of the component?

I've found some similar question but too old respect the actual reactjs and react router version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this. check for url change in `componentDidUpdate` if the current url does not match the previous make the API request again.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getPosts()
  }

  getPosts = () => {
    axios.get(endpoint.posts+'/getpost/'+this.props.match.params.id, cfg)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            thePost: res.data.thePost || ''
        });
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id) {
      this.getPosts()
    }
  }
```